# MWFeedParser Enclosures with Images

Tags: ios, rss

I have a pretty standard MWFeedParser project, except that instead of working with tableviews, I am working with collectionviews. To simplify things, I have the URL of the image I am trying to display in the enclosure part of the RSS feed. So if I call the url of item.enclosures, it will give the urls of the images. From there, how would I be able to display each image for each item in a CollectionView? I have the title and summary going to a UITextView, and I have a UIImageView all set up. Any ideas?

Comment: I am getting nil in **item.enclosures** why so??